# Connecting to Windows from Ubuntu via OpenSSH

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, ssh, openssh

When trying to establish a connection to a Windows 10 OpenSSH Server, the client on my Ubuntu machine fails to connect to the Windows host.

The server has been configured in the windows control panel to automatically start and I verified that it as started while attempting to connect to it. 
("Services" >> "OpenSSH SSH Server" >> "Properties")

I tried and failed to connect to the machine using my Ubuntu machine. I used the following command in the terminal, which uses "name" as the Windows device name and 192.XXX.XX.X as the local IP address found under "IP_v4 Address":

`ssh name@192.XXX.XX.X`

After waiting a significant amount of time, I received the following notice with a failed connection:

`ssh: connect to host 192.168.56.1 port 22: Connection timed out`

How can I fix the problems I experience when trying to connect to the server?

### Edit:

I created a new rule on my Windows machine to allow connections over port 22, but the same problem still persists.

"Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security" >> "Inbound Rules" >> "New Rule"

Comment: "name" shouldn't be the server name; it should be the username. Although I think your Windows firewall is blocking it as well.

Comment: Open the port in inbound traffic in windows firewall

Comment: @Biswapriyo After opening port 22 in Windows Firewall, the problem still persisted

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the windows device's name. You should be using a username from that windows device. For example, if your username were "Frank":

`ssh Frank@192.XXX.XX.X`